# Finding all unique values that add up to specific target value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more Pythonic way to find all combinations of numbers (each combination is made up of unique numbers) that add up to a specific target number. For example:

```
largest_single_number = 9  # in this example: single digits only
num_of_inputs = 5
target_sum = 30

# expected output:

0 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
1 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
2 + 4 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
2 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 9 = 30
3 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 9 = 30
3 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 = 30
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 30

number of possibilities:  7
```

The code we have looks like this:

```
counter = 0
largest_single_number = 9  # in this example: single digits only
num_of_inputs = 5  # Not used but dictates number of nested loops
target_sum = 30

for digit_1 in range(largest_single_number + 1):
    for digit_2 in range(digit_1 + 1, largest_single_number + 1):
        for digit_3 in range(digit_2 + 1, largest_single_number + 1):
            for digit_4 in range(digit_3 + 1, largest_single_number + 1):
                for digit_5 in range(digit_4 + 1, largest_single_number + 1):
                    if (
                        digi_sum := (digit_1 + digit_2 + digit_3 + digit_4 + digit_5)
                    ) == target_sum:
                        print(
                            f"{digit_1} + {digit_2} + {digit_3} + {digit_4} + {digit_5} = {target_sum}"
                        )
                        counter += 1
                    elif digi_sum > target_sum:
                        break

print("number of possibilities: ", counter)
```

We would appreciate knowing what's a more Pythonic way to achieve the SAME RESULT.

Comment: `itertools.combinations` can generate your candidate sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

- Check the equality in a [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
from itertools import combinations

values = [x for x in combinations(range(10), 5) if sum(x) == 30]

print(len(values))
>>> 7

print(values)

[(0, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (1, 5, 7, 8, 9),
 (2, 4, 7, 8, 9),
 (2, 5, 6, 8, 9),
 (3, 4, 6, 8, 9),
 (3, 5, 6, 7, 9),
 (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

### To get your expected output

```
for x in values:
    expected = ' + '.join(map(str, x)) + ' = 30'
    print(expected)

0 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
1 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
2 + 4 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
2 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 9 = 30
3 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 9 = 30
3 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 = 30
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 30
```

### As a function

```py
def calculation(largest: int, number: int, target: int) -> list:
    values = [x for x in combinations(range(largest + 1), number) if sum(x) == target]
    print(f'number of possibilites: {len(values)}')

    for x in values:
        print(' + '.join(map(str, x)) + f' = {target}')


calculation(9, 5, 30)

number of possibilites: 7
0 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
1 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
2 + 4 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 30
2 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 9 = 30
3 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 9 = 30
3 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 = 30
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 30
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a 1-liner (not counting the import):

```
from itertools import combinations

print("number of possibilities ",len([s for s in combinations(range(largest_single_number+1), num_of_inputs) if sum(s)== target_sum]))
```

I'll leave printing the individual sets as an exercise.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably use `itertools.combinations`

```py
possibilities = [combo for combo in 
    itertools.combinations(range(largest_single_number+1), num_of_inputs))
    if sum(combo) == target_sum]
```